# getServletContext().getRealPath("/") return wrong path

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, velocity

Background:
I want to learn the web development by using Velocity and servlet. I use the `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` to find the path of WEB-INF and the .vm file that is stored in /WEB-INF/templates/;

but the path return is :

```
E:\javaWorkSpcae\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\NewVelocity\templates\
```

what i want is :

```
E:\javaWorkSpcae\NewVelocity\WebContent\WEB-INF\templates\hello.vm
```

I use the `velocity-tools-1.4, tomcat1.7, jdk1.7`

the code i use is:

```
package velocityHandler;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.context.Context;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet;

 public class HelloHandler extends VelocityViewServlet{
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       private VelocityEngine velo;  

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException{  

           //velocity引擎对象                  
       velo = new VelocityEngine(); 

       //设置vm模板的装载路径
       Properties prop = new Properties();
       String path = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
       prop.setProperty(Velocity.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, path + "templates");

       System.out.println(path + "templates/");

       try {
          //初始化设置，下面用到getTemplate("*.vm")输出时
          //一定要调用velo对象去做,即velo.getTemplate("*.vm")
          velo.init(prop);
         } catch (Exception e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Template handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, Context ctx) throws Exception{

            String p1 = "Hoffman";
            String p2 = "Song";
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Vector personList = new Vector();
            personList.addElement(p1);
            personList.addElement(p2);
            ctx.put("theList", personList); //将模板数据 list放置到上下文环境context中

            Template template = velo.getTemplate("hello.vm");
            return template;
    }
}
```

who can give me a simple about servlet and velocity, I can not find good example in internet.

Comment: Don't try and use filesystem paths in a webapp context; load from classpath resources instead.

Comment: **Why** do you want to get this path? What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

`getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` will give you the root of the deployed location of your application which for a tomcat server in eclipse will be the path you are getting because your eclipse tomcat server runs in the directory indicated by that path.

The path `"/"` you asked for is the path that you would get if you typed "`applicationpath/`" into a browser.